# How to add spaces between variable in angular component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have below function from which i want to return slice character with count like below example.

Ex - abcd,test,red,blue,green,yellow

Expected output -

abcd,test,red,blue,g.........................(11)

My code is working fine but instead of --------- i want spaces between count.

```
viewMore(text) {
    if (text.tag_value_constraint && text.tag_value_constraint.values) {
      const enumText = text.tag_value_constraint.values[0];
      const count = 30;
      return enumText.slice(0, count) + (enumText.length > count ? "------("+(enumText.length - enumText.slice(0, count).length)+")" : "");
    }  
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```js
viewMore(text) {
  if (text.tag_value_constraint && text.tag_value_constraint.values) {
    const enumText = text.tag_value_constraint.values[0];
    const count = 30;
    return enumText.slice(0, count) + (enumText.length > count ? " (" + (enumText.length - enumText.slice(0, count).length) + ")" : "");
  }
}
```

Also, you can go with a cleaner approach by using string literals:

```js
viewMore(text) {
  if (text.tag_value_constraint && text.tag_value_constraint.values) {
    const enumText = text.tag_value_constraint.values[0];
    const count = 30;
    const additionalText = (enumText.length > count) ? ` (${(enumText.length - enumText.slice(0, count).length)})` : "";
    return enumText.slice(0, count) + additionalText;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First replace "------(" with " (" if you want single space if you need multiple spaces then do let me know.
2. Why do you calculate enumText.slice(0, count).length, when enumText.length > count then enumText.slice(0, count) always length count.

see the code below -

```
viewMore(text) {
if (text.tag_value_constraint && text.tag_value_constraint.values) {
  const enumText = text.tag_value_constraint.values[0];
  const count = 30;
  return enumText.slice(0, count) + (enumText.length > count ? " ("+(enumText.length - count)+")" : "");
}
```

}

For multiple spaces interpolation binding {{}} won't work - Use the binding in HTML file as `<p [innerHTML]="enumText"> </p>` whatever the variable name you are using to hold the value

in TS file you need to change code as below -

```
viewMore(text) {
if (text.tag_value_constraint && text.tag_value_constraint.values) {
  const enumText = text.tag_value_constraint.values[0];
  const count = 30;
  return enumText.slice(0, count) + (enumText.length > count ? " &#160; &#160; &#160; ("+(enumText.length - count)+")" : "");
}
```

}

Hope this will help you in solving your problem.

Comment: @saurabh can you check my answer below for the same - https://stackoverflow.com/a/62296040/5043867

Comment: No this is displaying &#160; &#160; &#160; instead of space bcz this is inside string

Comment: did you bind the value through [innerHTML]? if yes which version of angular are you using?

Comment: i am using angular 8

Answer (score 0):

```
 viewMore(text) {
      if (text.tag_value_constraint && text.tag_value_constraint.values) {
         const enumText = text.tag_value_constraint.values[0];
         const count = 30;
          return enumText.slice(0, count) + (enumText.length > count ? "      ("+ 
        (enumText.length - enumText.slice(0, count).length)+")" : "");
       `enter code here`}  
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below part as well -

```js
    const text = 'abcd,test,red,blue,green,yellow';

    function viewMore(text) {
      if (text) {
        const enumText = text[0];
        const count = 20;
        return text.slice(0, count) + ' '.repeat(text.length - count) + (text.length - count);
      }  
    }
    
    console.log(viewMore(text));
```